# How to implement drive.file scope to approve an app

Tags: google-drive-api

I am facing an issue approving my app that intends to implement an integration with Google Spreadsheets. I simply wanted to read spreadsheets and write to them. I implemented it using Google Spreadsheet scopes and everything worked just fine. I requested an approval of my app with this scope and Google responded to implement drive.file scope. I added that scope to my app in addition to Google Spreadsheets scope. Google is still asking me the following:-

"you should have access to https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file which should help you write spreadsheets. "

I am not 100% sure here what to do to get my app approved. Can anyone here guide through the steps required ?

Comment: Was your question resolved?

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just asking you to include the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope.

If you want, you can use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope instead to have full permission.

More of that in [Sheets API Authorizing Requests](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing)

Comment: Thanks. So yes the issue was that I was using drive.file scope that enables to read spreadsheets. But reading worksheets inside a spreadsheet requires auth/drive scope. I have now requested Google to enable 'drive' scope for my app.